# How to keep Unit tests and Integrations tests separate in pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing, pytest

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing#Description) and various [articles](https://techbeacon.com/devops/6-best-practices-integration-testing-continuous-integration) it is best practice to divide tests into Unit tests (run first) and Integration tests (run second), where Unit tests are typically very fast and should be run with every build in a CI environment, however Integration tests take longer to run and should be more of a daily run.

Is there a way to divide these in pytest? Most projects don't seem to have multiple test folders, so is there a way to make sure I only run Unit, Integration or both according to the situtation (CI vs daily builds)? When calculating test coverage, I assume I will have to run both.

Am I going about this the right way in attempting to divide the tests into these categories? Is there a good example somewhere of a project that has done this?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Yes, you can mark tests with the `pytest.mark` decorator.

Example:

```
def unit_test_1():
    # assert here

def unit_test_2():
    # assert here

@pytest.mark.integtest
def integration_test():
    # assert here
```

Now, from the command line, you can run `pytest -m "not integtest"` for only the unit tests, `pytest -m integtest` for only the integration test and plain `pytest` for all.

(You can also decorate your unit tests with `pytest.mark.unit` if you want, but I find that slightly tedious/verbose)

See the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html#mark-examples) for more information.

Comment: Ah this looks perfect Marcus! Do you agree that dividing the tests into unit and integration is a good idea for a python project using pytest? Is that what you do?

Comment: @Harlekuin if you mean in terms of metadata allowing them to be run separately, certainly; I too face the problem of larger-scale tests (and benchmarking) taking really long to run. If you mean in terms of directories, I would say that really depends on the project and the nature of the test. Hope I helped!

Comment: You definitely helped Marcus, I really appreciate it

Comment: Note that custom markers such as "integtest" should be registered into a pytest.ini file (see [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/markers.html#registering-markers)) otherwise, a warning will be raised

Comment: It's not a good idea to have unit tests and integration tests in the same file. Ideally they should be in a separate folder structure (as mentioned in the other answer)

Comment: to suppress the warning @yoyoog mentions in the pyproject.toml file. add `[tool.pytest.ini_options] markers = ["integtest"]` (with newlines)

Answer (score 87):

You can also *structurally separate* unit and integration tests into specific directories.  Here is a sample file structure from A. Shaw's [article](https://realpython.com/python-testing/#writing-integration-tests) *Getting Started With Testing in Python*:

[image]

With a structural approach, you:

1. do not need to manually mark various tests with attributes or `@pytest.mark`.
2. are not limited to a specific test runner.  See examples below.

---

**Examples**

Here we run various test runners on integration tests alone.  See the sample `project/` directory in the figure above.

With `unittest` from the standard library:

```
λ python -m unittest discover -s tests/integration
```

With `nose`:

```
λ nose tests/integration
```

With [`pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#specifying-tests-selecting-tests):

```
λ pytest tests/integration
```

Explicitly invoke the test runner on the `tests/` directory to run all tests:

```
λ pytest tests/
```

Alternatively, many test runners have an auto test-discovery mechanism that can find tests in sub-directories.

```
λ cd ..
λ pytest project/
```

Comment: Nice, I like the idea of not being bound to a specific test runner. Would most test runners be able to discover both unit and integration if you just passed the parent "tests" folder?

Comment: Possibly. I still use the older `nose` test runner, which can also handle this kind of discovery.  Consult the docs per library, as the command-line invocation will vary.

Comment: I can now confirm `pytest` also has [auto test-discovery](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html).

Comment: When separated like this, you can also run `pytest tests/unit tests/integration` to execute the integration tests after the unit tests.

Comment: In a case like this, how would you import my_app/helloworld.py inside tests/unit/ test_helloworld. I'm trying to follow this directory structure but imports can't seem to resolve for me.

Comment: you cannot get test coverage from both

Comment: @levgen toss them under "tox" and change the '--coverage' arguments to generate coverage for both.

Comment: @Rose Very good question. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73166679/4865723) which explains how to structure your project with the `src`-Layout and how to "install" it in _Development mode_ which makes you able to run the tests like described here.

Answer (score 3):

As of 2022 another option is the [pytest-integration](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-integration) package, which adds some additional functionality as compared to using `@pytest.mark` decorators alone.